# Apply comparision within group of rows to get one row per group

Tags: order-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table ordered by `fruit` and `date` resulting from a join such as the following:

```
+--------+------------+
| fruit  | date       |
+--------+------------+
| apple  | 2002-02-02 |
| apple  | 2003-03-03 |
| banana | 2001-01-01 |
| banana | 2003-03-03 |
| banana | 2022-02-02 |
+--------+------------+
```

How do I extract the earliest date for each fruit? The result should be

```
+--------+------------+
| fruit  | date       |
+--------+------------+
| apple  | 2002-02-02 |
| banana | 2001-01-01 |
+--------+------------+
```

Comment: [Help me write this query in SQL](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2976/32281)

Comment: Sorry, I should have searched more diligently.  However, the information provided is rather more than I require.  I just needed the pointer to ```GROUP BY``` and ```MIN``` and was then able to do ```SELECT name,MIN(date) FROM fruit GROUP BY name;```